# I have a react table im trying to get it to sort when I click on the this different table Heads

Tags: reactjs, filter, tablesorter

I would assume the issue is coming from signaling portion of the code and the format I have set it in but from all accounts, this should work I know I can break it into an if-else statement but this is the absolute first thing I have created in React and I am trying to use this format. I provided the whole code for the table but the rest is working properly it's just the sorting I am trying to get to work any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Also if there is anything else in the code you see that I could improve upon as well am open to all suggestions to learn and improve, my search filter is having issues as well but I'm hoping to resolve that.

```
enter class AppTable extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        users: [],
       sorted: '',
        directory: 'asc',
        compile: [],
    };
}
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(`https://randomuser.me/api/?results=20&nat=us`)
            .then(res => {
                let users = (res && res.data) ? res.data.results: [];
              if (!users || users.length === 0){
                    this.setState({loading: false});
                    return;
                }
                const tableList = users.map(state => new User(state));
                this.setState({ compile: tableList, users: tableList });
            })
    }

    sorting(sorted) {
        const currentField = this.state.sorted;
        const users = this.state.users;
        let directory = this.state.directory;
        if (currentField === sorted) {
            directory = directory === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc'
           }else{
            directory = 'asc'
           }
        this.signaling(users, sorted,directory);
        this.setState({users: users, directory: directory, sorted: sorted})
    }

    **signaling(objects, field, direction){
        const signal = direction === "asc" ? 1 : -1
        objects.sort((a,b) => (a[field] > b[field]) ? signal * 1 : ((b[field] > a[field]) ? signal * -1 : 0));
    }**

    initSearch(evt) {
        const searchValue = evt.target.value;
        const compile = this.state.compile;
        if (!searchValue){
            this.setState({users: compile});
            return;
        }
        const filtering = compile.filter((object)=>{
            return Object.keys(object).reduce((acc, curr)=>{
                return acc || object[curr].toLowerCase().includes(searchValue);
            }, false);
        });
        this.setState({users: filtering});
    }

    render() {
        const throughput = this.state.users;
        return <Col>
            <Form inline className="mb-2">
                    <Form.Label className="my-1 mr-2">Search:</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type="text" onChange={event => this.initSearch(event)} placeholder="Search Table" />
            </Form>
            <Table striped bordered hover>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th className="pointer" onClick={() => this.sorting(`${this.firstName}`)}>First Name</th>
                    <th className="pointer" onClick={() => this.sorting(`${this.lastName}`)}>Last Name</th>
                    <th className="pointer" onClick={() => this.sorting(`${this.email}`)}>Email</th>
                    <th className="pointer" onClick={() => this.sorting(`${this.street}`)}>Street</th>
                    <th className="pointer" onClick={() => this.sorting(`${this.city}`)}>City</th>
                    <th className="pointer" onClick={() => this.sorting(`${this.state}`)}>State</th>
                    <th className="pointer" onClick={() => this.sorting(`${this.phone}`)}>Phone</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {throughput.map((individual, index) => (
                    <AppRow key={index} user={individual}/>
                ))}
                </tbody>
            </Table>
        </Col>;
    }
}

export default AppTable;
```

Comment: Btw, you can simple `this.firstName` instead of `\`${this.firstName}\``.

Comment: Thank you for that like I said any tips on any part of it are appreciated =)